# SQL define table for treelike structure

Tags: sql

In previous versions of Visual studio there was a way to build DB using diagrams.

In 2012 they took out that possibility.

I need to create script which creates table for category tree.

```
    CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Categories]
(
    [Id] INT NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY IDENTITY, 
    [Name] NVARCHAR(50) NOT NULL, 
    [ParentId] INT NOT NULL DEFAULT 0, 
    [FK_Parent] int FOREIGN KEY ([ParentId]) REFERENCES [Categories]([Id]) NOT NULL
)
```

If I create table like this, I cannot add top level records.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Define top-level records as having a `NULL` `FK_Parent`.  Just change your definition to allow nulls.

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Categories]
(
    [Id] INT NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY IDENTITY, 
    [Name] NVARCHAR(50) NOT NULL, 
    [ParentId] INT NOT NULL ,
    ---llow NULL FK_Parent for top-level
    CONSTRAINT [FK_Parent] FOREIGN KEY ([ParentId]) REFERENCES [Categories]([Id])
)
```

Comment: When removed default value from ParentId it finally worked - thanks.

Comment: One thing - In show data there are two columns ParentId and FK_Parent why is that?

Comment: @SpoksST You defined two columns. If what you wanted was a name for the FK, that is done differently. I'll add above.

Comment: [ParentId]   INT           NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([Id] ASC),
    FOREIGN KEY ([ParentId]) REFERENCES [dbo].[Categories] ([Id]) got the result I needed